# Javascript menu behaviour inverted if mouse is on menu when page is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting crazy with my javascript menu. The website is [DDay.it](http://www.dday.it) and the menu is a javascript pull down with ajax loading. I'm trying to fight an issue that is quite annoying: if the mouse is on the menu (accidentaly) when the page is loading, the behaviour of the menu is inverted: normal state open, hover state closed.

You can try live on the website using Chrome.

I want to solve it by myself (I'm a rails developer but I'm learning js) , but I cannot figure why the behaviour change on page loading if js are loaded and executed at the end of the page...

Added the code: here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/robypez/4f4630509480baca40c1)

Comment: How about showing the code which is responsible for attaching the mouse in/out handler? I would assume that the handlers just toggle a "visible-flag" instead of setting it to true/false in the in/out handler.

Comment: ^^^ This. I just tried looking at the source of your website, it is brutal due to the minification. Anyway, you may want to wrap your menu initialisation code in a `$(document).ready(function(){ window.headerManager.init(); });` block if you haven't already (assuming you're using jQuery too).

Comment: What @MightyLampshade says. I'd like to add that even without jQuery, it's almost always better to wait for the document ready event for manipulating the DOM... :)

Comment: I added the GIST with the entire code. I don't write this javascript, we outsource the script (and I cannot contact the creator). I just need to identify the broken function...

Comment: I will try to wrap in a document ready...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The faulty code is in line 232:
`$navContainer.addClass('animating').toggleClass('open');`

It belongs to the function `animateMenuToggle` which should receive a status parameter (can be passed by the function `toogleMenu`).

Then, you can use the status parameter to do something like:
`$navContainer.addClass('animating').removeClass('open close').addClass(status);`

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, I guess, you do not get the event of the `mouseenter` on the navigation while loading.

Then on `mouseleave` you get the event and turning all around.

You have dependencies on `.hasClass('animating')` which could flip it.

I greatly suppose to make a switch either on `.hasClass()` or on `status == open/close`.

Comment: Pro-Tip: Do not let the user wait for the content of the pull-down to load before animating it. That is bad #UX. The user will click on the link or go to another site, before the pull-down comes. It is taking too long.